# Assign All Product categories to all my product programmatically

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i have 32 category and 1000 product in my site ..but my client want to add a category All Product and in this category he wants to show all product so when user click on this category all product show

```
i have try this like get product category and them get the all prodcut category term_id and then use the
wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $term_ids, 'product_cat' ); 
but does not work
this is the code 
$product_id = 5558; 
$term_ids = [ 130, 12, 18 ];
wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $term_ids, 'product_cat' );

no error that code is not add that category to this product
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<?php 

//Get all Terms
$args_cat = array(
    'taxonomy'   => "product_cat",
     'hide_empty' => false,
);
$product_categories = get_terms( $args_cat );

$term_ids = array();
foreach ( $product_categories as $product_categories_key => $product_categories_value ) {
   $term_ids[] = $product_categories_value->term_id;
}


//Get all Products
$args_product = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$loop_product = new WP_Query( $args_product );

while ( $loop_product->have_posts() ) : $loop_product->the_post();

    global $product;
    $id = $product->get_id();

    wp_set_object_terms( $id, $term_ids, 'product_cat' );

    echo get_the_title();

endwhile;

wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: thanx let me try

Comment: check my latest edit, you need to add `'hide_empty' => false,`

Comment: that code not working like i have 500 product for different category but i creat a new category all product and its term id is 130 and i want all product under also this category